# Question about inequality and logarithms

Tags: inequality, logarithms

Let's say we have an inequality:

$x < y$

does this hold true?

$\log x < \log y$

and if so, how can I prove it?

Comment: only if $x,y>0$

Comment: $\log$ is an increasing function and what Dr.Sonnhard Graubner said.

Comment: $\log_a$ is a strictly increasing function when $a>1$ and strictly decreasing when $0<a<1$.

Comment: How you prove this depends on how you define $\log x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\log_{B}{x}=a$ and $\log_{B}{y}=b$ for $B>0$. Then $ x=B^{a} $ and $ y=B^{b} $. So we can write $$x<y\Rightarrow B^{a}<B^{b}.$$
If $0<B\leq 1$, then

$$\begin{eqnarray}
B^{a}<B^{b} & \Rightarrow & a>b \\ & \Rightarrow & \log_{B}{x}>\log_{B}{y}
\end{eqnarray}
$$but otherwise (say $B>1$),

$$\begin{eqnarray}
B^{a}<B^{b} & \Rightarrow & a<b \\ & \Rightarrow & \log_{B}{x}<\log_{B}{y}
\end{eqnarray}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $f(x)=\log_a (x)\Rightarrow f'(x)=\frac{1}{\ln (a) x}$